# How do modify my code to bypass the SettingWithCopyWarning with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, integer

I am trying to convert the 'reviews' column from a string to an integer and ran into a SettingWithCopyWarning, and I'm not quite sure why I received this warning. Is there a more effective to convert a string to an integer using pandas?

```
yesstyle['reviews'] = yesstyle['reviews'].str.replace(',','').astype('int64')
```

Comment: The culprit is usually on a line before the SettingWithCopyWarning line. If `yesstyle` is created using a square bracket slice, such as `yesstyle = df[boolean_mask]`, try adding `.copy()` after the brackets, turning this example into `yesstyle = df[boolean_mask].copy()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.